# Force a (enter) in os.execute() in Lua

Tags: email, lua, send, freebsd, enter

I want to force a enter in os.execute(). Im using Lua on FreeBSD and I want to write an email.

If I write this:

```
os.execute('mail -v -s \'Hello Im the Topic\' mail@hotmail.de')
os.execute('Hello this should be the message')
os.execute('.')
```

it doesnt work, I receive an email without any content, just the topic comes trough. Also, i get some errors in freebsd ('Hello this should be the message' is no command ... blabla)

So i want to force an (enter) in one os.execute.
I tried:

```
os.execute('mail -v -s \'Hello Im the Topic\' mail@hotmail.de\nHello this should be a message\n.')
```

and

```
os.execute('mail -v -s \'Hello Im the Topic\' mail@hotmail.de\
Hello this should be a message\
.')
```

but both doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `io.popen` to open a pipe to the command you want to execute and write to it the data you to send:

```
local f=io.popen('mail -v -s \'Hello Im the Topic\' mail@hotmail.de','w')
f:write[[
Hello this should be a message
.
]]
f:close()
```

Comment: It works fine for me. What does not work for you? Do you get a Lua error? Try removing `local`.

Comment: print("Started")
 local f=io.popen('mail -v -s \'Hello Im the Topic\' mail@hotmail.de','w')
f:write[[
Hello this should be a message
.
]]
f:close()
 print("Executed")

it only shows "started" but not executed, no error

Comment: nothing ... only "Started" again. I removed the local, too